# iOS Simulator - Physical Macbook keyboard not giving input in flutter app

Tags: ios, flutter

While testing I've been having an issue for a while now.
Typing in-app only works via the software keyboard from the simulator itself. Physical input on my mac does not work. This is **only inside the app**, in an app like safari it does work.

This only occurs on iOS, Android works fine.

Anyone else had this issue?

*Note that enabling phyiscal keyboard in the simulator's settings does not do anything for me.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is an issue while using the iOS simulator and Mac's keyboard in flutter apps. More importantly, the flutter team mentions that this should not happen on a physical device. Just in case it happens on a physical device, they've asked the developers to report the issue. I have faced this issue on iOS simulators but not on an actual device.

Comment: An actual device works fine yes. Unfortunate that this hasn't been fixed then...
Either way, thanks for your comment!